# Perl - How to open directory - Return name of lowest numerically numbered filename using posix and or abs?

Tags: perl, sorting, posix

Well I am back again, stuck on another seemingly simple routine.
I need to figure out how to do this with Perl.

1- I open a directory full of files named 1.txt, 2.txt ~ 100.txt.

(But sometimes the lowest numbered filename could in fact be any number (27.txt) due to 0-26.txt already removed from directory.)

(I found out how to implement ABS sort so; 1,2,3 not 1,10,11 ~ 2,20 was the order returned.)

```
    use POSIX;
    my @files = </home/****/users/*.txt>;
    foreach $file (@files) {
    ##$file ABS($file)
    ##and so on..
    ##EXAMPLE NOT TRIED
    }
```

2- I just want to return the lowest numbered file name in the directory into a $var.

Do I have to read the whole directory into an array, do an abs sort, then grab the first one in the array off?

Is there a more efficient way to grab the lowest numbered file?

More info:

The files were created by/with a loop so, I also contemplated grabbing the oldest file first if the creation time is actually that sensitive. But, I am a beginner and don't know if creation time is accurate enough, and how to use it or if in fact that is a viable solution.

Thanks for the help, I always find the best people here.

Comment: I also thought of using creation time as the file name in the "creation loop" but, I was still stuck at reading it all into an array and grabbing the first one off.

Comment: I don’t see any use of the POSIX module in the proffered  code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp qw(read_dir);
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catfile);

my $directory = 'some/directory';
my @files = read_dir($directory);
my @ordered;
{
    no warnings 'numeric';
    @ordered = sort { $a <=> $b } @files;
}

my $lowest_file = catfile $directory, $ordered[0];
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. Close to what I had but, your version is fewer lines and also taught me a new trick! Guess there is no system call or one liner for this function because I am prob saving the files incorrectly in the first place. Thanks Again!

Comment: **ICK!** It’s pretty silly to load a module — and a *non-standard* one at that — just because you are afraid of the built-in `readdir` function! Why don’t you show how to do this in **Pure Perl?**  You know, only pragmata allowed. Otherwise you’re just begging to be afflicted with the same class of problem you get today with all these crippled people who can’t even add two short numbers together without a calculator in their hands.